# how to rewrite zip() function in if and for loop

Tags: python

I have a code like this:

```
def grade(state):
    
    for s, p in zip("ox", [[-1,-2,-3,-4],[1,2,3,4]]):
        if (state == s).all(axis=1).any(): return p[0]
        if (state == s).all(axis=0).any(): return p[1]
        if (np.diagonal(state) == symbol).all(): return p[2]   
        if (np.diagonal(np.rot90(state)) == symbol).all(): return p[3]
    
    return 0
```

In a matrix 3*3 I am trying to show each column returns either -1 or 1, on each row returns -2 or 2, on diagonal move it returns -3 or 3 and the other diagonal move shows -4 or 4.
how can I change it to something like this:

```
def grade(state):

    for s in ['o','x']:
        if s == 'o':
           ...
        elif s == 'x':
            ...
        
    return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a `zip`'d sequence of keys and mapped values in general is more readable and Pythonic than using a set of if-elif-else statements to decide the mapped value given a key.

If you must convert it to if-else statements, you can observe the pattern of the mapped values of a given key. In this very case, the only difference that having `s` equal to `'o'` (versus `'x'`) makes, is that the returning values are negated as a result. You therefore can set a multiplier of -1 or 1 depending on the value of `s`, and multiply the returning value by the multiplier:

```
def grade(state):
    for s in 'o', 'x':
        if s == 'o':
            multiplier = -1
        else:
            multiplier = 1
        if (state == s).all(axis=1).any(): return p[0] * multiplier
        if (state == s).all(axis=0).any(): return p[1] * multiplier
        if (np.diagonal(state) == symbol).all(): return p[2] * multiplier
        if (np.diagonal(np.rot90(state)) == symbol).all(): return p[3] * multiplier

    return 0
```